# How to display something untill i press button?

Tags: java

How to display output (W IS PRESSED) until i press w and when i release w then output will display as (W is released).

```
System.out.println("HI");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();
while(str.equals("w"))
{
    System.out.println("W IS PRESSED");
}
```

Comment: Even with a scanner, I think you would need to press enter to complete the input of `w`.  This sounds like the job for a keyboard listener.

Comment: You can't do that with the `System.in` / `System.out` interface. You need to build a GUI interface to have that kind of insight into what is happening with the keyboard. Look into AWT/Swing for that.

Comment: I thought event handlers like key listener is only available in GUI like Swing @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Here's an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html